# Looking for a Clean File Host

Tags: uploading

I have a Blogger blog and I would like to have a way for readers to download files (Blogger doesn't host files like that.) I would use something like github, but one of my files is actually just a spreadsheet make with OpenOffice Calc that has a function on it -- not really something for GitHub.

Where is a great place to upload this where users can download the files if they want?

I know there are a lot of those ad-ridden "get paid to have people download files from you" type of sites and that's exactly what I would like to avoid.

Anyone know of a (hopefully) free place I can dump files so that people can download them that isn't junky, ad-ridden, scammy, dirty, or virus-filled place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MediaFire,](http://www.mediafire.com/) [FileDropper,](http://www.filedropper.com/) [Wuala,](http://www.wuala.com/) [box.net,](http://www.box.net) and [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) all allow file upload and sharing of public download links.

See also this [comparison of file hosting services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_hosting_services) on Wikipedia.